# How to send email of webpage as an attachment using Spring Boot, JavaScript, Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, pdf, mime-message

I have implemented a feature to generate invoice in PDF format. So basically there are two buttons one for print and another one for Email. So when user clicks on email button then the invoice should be sent to specific email.

The thing is I am bit confused about the implementation. So If any one have any suggestion, would be appreciable.

[image: Screenshot to display email invoice]

[image: Screenshot to display generated PDF]

Comment: This same PDF that you are displaying to the user in the Browser must have been generated in a previous step?

When they click the Email button, send an email (using Java-Mail) or (spring-boot-mail) and attach that same PDF file.

Comment: Yes, when user clicks on Print button, then in new window PDF of invoice is opened and then one can take print or can simple save that PDF file to their local machines. So my question is, Do I need to do same thing for email button to send that generated PDF through email?

Comment: The Email button needs to be implemented in your backend.  When the user clicks email, it will call /email method that will then (Generate PDF, Create Email, Send Email)

Comment: Do you have any example or any link of tutorial or something so that I can get some idea about it?

Comment: Does the sample answer below help you @Rakhi

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mail")
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    public EmailService emailService;


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/send"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendEmailWithAttachment(Model model,
                             HttpServletRequest request) {

             //Logic to create PDF file

            emailService.sendMessageWithAttachment(to,subject,body, pdfFile);

    }
```

---

```
public interface EmailService{

      sendMessageWithAttachment(
          String to, String subject, String text, String pathToAttachment, FileSystemResource pdfFileToSend); 

}
```

---

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender emailSender;

  @Override
  public void sendMessageWithAttachment(
  String to, String subject, String text, String pathToAttachment, FileSystemResource pdfFileToSend) {
    // ...
    
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
     
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    
    helper.setFrom("noreply@baeldung.com");
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText(text);
    
    helper.addAttachment("PDFFile", pdfFileToSend);

    emailSender.send(message);
    // ...
}
```

---

Your Javascript then calls this /mail/send endpoint, which should generate the PDF for this user, create an Email, and send Email using spring-boot-mail-starter

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

References:

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/send-email-with-attachment/#5

Comment: I will update you soon. Thank you.